# Is there a matrix $A$ such that for every other matrix $B$, we have $\mbox{tr}(AB) = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm struggling to prove/disprove this notion. I've figured if such matrix exists, it has to be nilpotent and non-invertible, and the sum of its eigenvalues is 0. Can anyone chip in?

Edit : Oh yeah, $A \neq 0$

Comment: Yes, you can take $A=0$.

Comment: Maybe try $A=0$?

Comment: Oh my bad, I forgot to state A can't be zero. Let me edit my post

Comment: It can *only* be the zero matrix $A=0$ for real matrices. You cannot exclude it, otherwise there is no such $A$.

Comment: Wouldn't considering $1 \times 1$ matrices over any field disprove the claim?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Don't forget to mark the most useful answer as accepted by clicking the little green check mark. You now also have the required reputation to vote up any questions and answers you like.

Comment: @B.Swan: No. That would be like saying "Are there two nonzero matrices $A, B$ such that $AB = 0$?" and saying "No because there aren't any $1 \times 1$ matrices that do that", but that's obviously wrong.

Comment: @Kundor so what would the matrix A be for 1x1 matrices? if there is none the conjecture doesnt Hold for 1x1 matrices and thus doesnt hold for all matrices

Comment: @Kundor the key phrase in the conjecture is "for every other matrix"

Comment: @Kundor alright, and we have found that such an A does not exist for 1x1 matrices. what does that mean for the claim?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77644/discussion-between-kundor-and-b-swan).

Comment: kundor is right

Answer (score 40):

Another sensible approach here: let $E_{ij}$ denote the matrix whose $i,j$ entry is $1$ and whose other entries are zeros.  Show that
$$
\operatorname{tr}(AE_{ji}) = a_{ij}
$$
This can only be zero for all $i,j$ if $A$ is the zero matrix.

---

A nifty trick in proving the above is to note that $E_{ij} = e_ie_j^T$, where $e_i$ denotes the $i$th standard basis vector.  In particular, we have
$$
\operatorname{tr}(AE_{ji}) = \operatorname{tr}(Ae_je_i^T) = \operatorname{tr}(e_i^TAe_j) = e_i^TAe_j = a_{ij}
$$

Comment: Not just sensible, essential in the general (not necess real/complex) case.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick! Sorry for all the mess in forgetting notions, it's my first time here. Again, thanks for the kindness!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: It occurs to me that this proof fails for the matrix $E_{11}$ since we only know $\text{tr}(AB)=0$ for "every other matrix" $B$. But I am not being entirely serious.

Comment: @ancientmathematician no no, you've misinterpreted.  It's "every other matrix", as in every two matrices.  So $\operatorname{tr}(AE_{12}) = 0$, but $\operatorname{tr}(AE_{13}) \neq 0$

Comment: I'm missing something I guess. I read the question as saying $\text{tr}(AB)=0$ for all $B\not=A$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician oh, I thought we were just making jokes now

Answer (score 33):

Let $B=A^t$.  Then $\operatorname{trace}(AA^t)$ is the sum of squares of all coefficients of the real matrix $A$.  If this is zero then $A=0$.  So the zero matrix is the only possibility.

Somebody should have gotten around to pointing out that the underlying fundamental fact is that the [Hilbert-Schmidt operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) provides a norm on the space of matrices, also known as the Frobenius norm.

Comment: The question didn't say that the coefficients are from $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @lisyarus in that case the same basic trick works; we can take $\operatorname{tr}(AA^*)$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Do you mean complex matrices? This isn't mentioned either. The coefficients could come from an arbitrary ring.

Comment: @lisyarus that's a fair point...

Answer (score 4):

Other answers have presented proofs that this must be the zero matrix, but here are some general avenues of attack for analyzing a set S of matrices, applied to the case where S is the set of matrices with your property.

1. **Is it closed under addition?** 
   $tr(M_1+M_2)=tr(M_1)+tr(M_2)$, hence $tr((A_1+A_2)B)=tr(A_1B)+tr(A_2B)$. With a bit more work, it can be shown that S is a group under addition.
2. **Is it closed under multiplication?**

   Given $A$ in S, we have $tr(ACB)$ = $tr(A(CB))$, which, since $A$ is in S, is zero. But it can also be written as $tr((AC)B)$.  So given any $A$ in S and arbitrary $C$, $AC$ is in S. Thus, S is an ideal. (Technically, I've shown that it's a right ideal, but not that it's a left ideal, but that follows from $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$).
3. **What entries have to be non-zero?** Since S is an ideal, we can permute any element of S and the result will be an element of S. So if an element of S has any non-zero entry, we can permute that entry to be $a_{11}$. We can also scale it to be 1. So if there are any nontrivial elements of S, then there is an element for which $a_{11}$ is 1
4. **Is $E_{ij}$ in S (where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with $a_{ij} = 1$ and zero elsewhere)?** If we have an element $A$ of S whose $a_{11}$ entry is 1, then $E_{11}A= E_{11}$ ( where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with $a_{ij} = 1$ and zero elsewhere). So if there are any nontrivial elements of S, then $E_{11}$ is in S. A similar proof applies to any $E_{ij}$.

At this point, we've reached an absurdity, as $E_{11}$ is clearly not in S.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the interest of the question appears more clearly when introducing the $K$-vector space $M_n(K)$ of $n\times n$ matrices with coefficients in $K$ (where $K$ is any field) endowed with the map $(A, B)\to <A,B>:= tr(AB^t)$. This map is a $K$-bilinear symmetric form : $K$-bilinearity is routine, and the symmetry comes from the well known identities $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$ and $tr(C^t)=tr(C)$. The OP question can be reformulated as : is the form <.,.> *non degenerate*, in other words is it a *scalar product* (but note that this last terminology is not a universal standard) ?

Now $M_n(K)$ has dimension $n^2$, with a canonical basis consisting of the elementary matrices $E_{ij}$ whose entries are $0$ except the $(i,j)$ entry which is $1$. It is an easy calculation (or a "nifty trick" in Omnomnomnom's words) to show that $tr(E_{ij}E_{hk})$ is the $(kh)$ entry of $E_{ij}$, so that $<E_{ij},E_{kh}>=1$ if $(i,j)=(k,h)$, $0$ otherwise. This means that the $ E_{ij}$'s form an *orthonormal basis* of $M_n(K)$. If we rewrite this basis as  $\epsilon_1 ,...,\epsilon_{n^2}$ (the order is arbitrary), and denote the coordinates of $A,B$ in this basis by $(\alpha_i,\beta_j)$, then $<A,B>=\alpha_1\beta_1 +...+\alpha_{n^2}\beta_{n^2}$, a well known expression. Note that although the bilinear form <.,.> is non degenerate, the associated quadratic form defined by $Q(A)=<A,A>$ is not necessarily *definite*, i.e. it can admit non zero *isotropic* vectors since the solutions of the equation $Q(A)=0$ depend on the base field.

Answer (score 1):

@Omnomnomnom's answer works over any unital ring. What if the ring is non-unital?

Well then, there are beasts like the quotient of $2\Bbb Z$ by the ideal $4\Bbb Z$. It has two elements, $\bar 0$ and  $\bar 2$, of which all possible products, that is $\ \bar 0\times \bar 0$, $\ \bar 0\times \bar 2,\ $$\bar 2\times \bar 2$, are equal to $\bar 0$. It follows, since the entries of a product matrix are made of (sums of) products of entries, that **any** matrix $A\in \mathcal{M}_{n, n}(2\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z)$, $A\neq 0$,  satisfies the required property that for all $B\in \mathcal{M}_{n, n}(2\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z)$, $\operatorname{Tr}(AB)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

No. For $A\not=0$ we have $\mathrm{tr}(AA^\top)>0$.

This is because $AA^\top$ is positive semi-definite (see [Gramian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix)), hence its trace (as the sum of all the non-negative eigenvalues) is positive unless $A$ was zero.